# Python pytest-mock assert_has_calls

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock, pytest-mock

I am looking into the excellent pytest plugin called pytest-mock (https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock), and now I am trying some examples with assert_has_calls. In short I am testing an instance of class B, more specifically how that instance interact with an instance of class A (in which I have mocked the method 'time_consuming_task').

The example is working with alt. B (see comments in code). I would prefer alt. A, and instead mock the method in class A directly, instead of mocking the method in the instance of class A accessed through the instance (obj) of class B.

```
class A(object):
    def do_time_consuming_task(self, timeout):
        return True


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def do_work(self, timeout):
        return self.a.do_time_consuming_task(timeout)


def test_calls(mocker):
    # Prepare
    obj = B()
    #mock_a = mocker.patch.object(A, 'do_time_consuming_task', autospec=True)  # Alt. A
    mock_a = mocker.patch.object(obj.a, 'do_time_consuming_task', autospec=True)  # Alt. B
    mock_a.return_value = True

    # Exercise
    obj.do_work(timeout=100)
    obj.do_work(timeout=50)

    # Assert
    mock_a.assert_has_calls([mocker.call(100), mocker.call(50)])
```

Answer (score 6):

Managed to figure it out with the help of another answer provided by the author of pytest-mock.

The assert should be called as follows if using alt. A:

```py
mock_a.assert_has_calls([mocker.call(mocker.ANY, 100), mocker.call(mocker.ANY, 50)])
```